# Using the QGraphicsView Method Scene() to Assign a QGraphicsScene Variable

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

What would the syntax look like if I wanted to even use `QGraphicsView::scene()` in the first place? My goal is to change the scale of a `pixmap` in my graphics view object with sliders. I want to use `QgraphicsView::scene()` and `QScene::itemsAt()` etc. to find the original `pixmap` and then use `QPixmap::scaled()` (this I found would be the only way to ensure my cosmetic property set for the `pixmap` holds true). However I am having issues with the syntax of `QGraphicsView::scene()`. My attempt is below. I am also creating a Qt widget application for context.

```
QGraphicsViewScene graphicsScene = ui->PixmapView->scene();
QGraphicsPixmapItem graphicsPixmapItem = graphicsScene.itemAt(0, 0);
```

edit
If I was to store my QPixmap pixmap* as a member variable I am not entirely sure how to implement that where it remains in scope for my slots.

edit
static member variables?

Comment: This should be QGraphicsScene* graphicsScene, not QGraphicsView

Comment: Why don't you just store your `QGraphicsPixmapItem*` as a member variable?

Comment: @thuga how would I go about doing that sorry

Comment: *I know C syntax and how I would create a class with member variables. I am just not sure how I would do this in qt so that the class is in the scope of multiple slots and functions.

Comment: Are these slots and functions members of the same class that contains your scene?

Comment: *C++ syntax. I don't believe there is a class that actually contains my scene. I just simple initialised a scene in the openAction_triggered() slot and didn't delete the scene pointer

Comment: @thuga would you be able to show me how I would use QGraphicsPixmapItem* as a member variable. If you enter it as an answer I will most likely accept it, I believe it would solve my problem if you are able to access that member variable from various slots.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `QGraphicsPixmapItem` object a member variable of your class. Then you would be able to access it from any of your class member functions.

Here is a quick example:

```
class MyClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        // create graphics view, scene, etc..
    }

public slots:
    void openActionTriggered()
    {
        ...
        myItem = scene->addPixmap(myPixmap); // you can create your item however you want.. this is just an example
    }
    void mySlot()
    {
        if(myItem)
        {
            // do something with myItem
        }
    }

private:
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *myItem = nullptr; // myItem is a member variable of 
    QGraphicsScene *scene = nullptr; // I made scene a member variable so it can be accessed from any member functions
}
```

Comment: That is a good point, I was hoping to be able to use my implementation. But I appreciate the work around. I will test it out and hopefully not get the same issue.